# как установить pip? windows 7 64 bit

Tags: python, pip

```
pip install pycrypto

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install pycrypto': ?? ??????? ????? ????????? ????.
```

Comment: Попробуйте обновить его `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: Зачем его устанавливать он с Python идёт?